# Is there any way to stream online videos in python tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am doing a mini project, where I need to create labels using tkinter library of python. I need to attach a link to each of the label, so that whenever I will click on a particular label, it should stream its online video. Videos can be YouTube videos. So I was wondering is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot easily do what you want. Tkinter has no way to render html. You would have to parse the HTML and CSS and Javascript yourself, and translate the information for display on a canvas or text widget.